# ASP.NET issue with System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider: The network address is invalid

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, active-directory, ldap

I have an Azure VM running Windows Server 2008 with Active directory instance listing test users. I do also have Azure SQL test database. I would like to access this DB and the AD from a ASP.NET MVC app running in IIS in my local PC.

I am able to log in as a user that is listed in the Azure VM AD (ADRoleConnectionString is working) but then System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider Initialize throws an error when I try to get some additional information about the users for this app referenced in the DB.

Stack trace:

> ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The network address is invalid.
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext.IsContextValid(DirectoryContext context, DirectoryContextType contextType)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext.IsContextValid(DirectoryContext context, DirectoryContextType contextType)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext.isServer()
>      at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetDomain(DirectoryContext context)
>      at System.Web.Security.DirectoryInformation.InitializeDomainAndForestName()
>      at System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.Initialize(String name, NameValueCollection config)
>      at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
>      at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders(ProviderSettingsCollection configProviders, ProviderCollection providers, Type providerType)
>      at System.Web.Security.Membership.InitializeSettings(Boolean initializeGeneralSettings, RuntimeConfig appConfig, MembershipSection settings)
>      at System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize()
>      at System.Web.Security.Membership.get_Provider()

The connection strings are:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://address-to-azure:389/OU=users,OU=myservice,DC=servicedomain,DC=com" />
<add name="ADRoleConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://address-to-azure:389/OU=users,OU=myservice,DC=servicedomain,DC=com" />

...

<add name="MY_ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" enableSearchMethods="true" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" connectionProtection="None" connectionUsername="testUser@servicedomain.com" connectionPassword="password" applicationName="MyTestApp" />
```

This works when I deploy the app to the Azure VM IIS but not from my local PC IIS. I have port 389 open both TCP and UDP and I am able to list view users by using Active directory explorer tool without problems. My local active directory instance (localhost:389) works also without problems.

- I have tried to change the IIS application pool identity but it did not help.
- If I change ADConnectionString path OU=users,OU=myservice,DC=servicedomain,DC=com to something that does not exist in the AD I get an error: The container specified in the connection string does not exist. This proofs that the network address is valid as such because it is aware of the Azure AD path existence.

I am totally out of ideas what might be the issue. Does anyone have idea what might be the problem?